# How can I continue to iterate in a while controller even if I have a failed assertion in Jmeter?

Tags: java, while-loop, jmeter, controller, assertion

This is what I am doing.
I am using a While controller to iterate a CSV data file. I set "STOP THREAD ON EOF" to true in the element "CSV Data Set Config" because I want to read all the data in the file.

Then I'm using the data extracted to make two http requests and then compare the responses to see if there are any differences (these are two soap requests using the same body request but reading from two different databases). I am using a BeanShell assertion to compare the response: if there is no difference I am using `prev.setSuccessful(true);` and so I have a green light; if there is some difference I am using `prev.setSuccessful(false);` and so I have a red light in my results tree. Doing this way as soon as I find a difference my iteration stops, but I would like to continue until I read all the data in the CSV file and I still want to have a red light so I can easily check where I have errors. My CSV file contains thousands of records and I want to make my http requests with all the data. Is that possibile even if I have a failed assertion?

This is my project tree.

[image: This is my project tree.]

Thank you !

Comment: You could collect the results in a list. Meaning you add the CSV record to a list an apply an additional indicator if the test was successful or not

Comment: @XtremeBaumer could you explain please? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue putting `${__javascript("false")}` in the While Controller condition

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter doesn't break any loops and should just continue in case of error. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it should contain the reason of stopping the test.

So double check your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration and make sure that "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" is set to `Continue`

[image]

Also be informed that using Beanshell is a some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to the [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial).

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, thank you for your response. My Thread Group configuration is as what you posted. It seems there is no errors in my log file. There is just a final line `o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)`.   This is my assertion: `if ( errors.toString().isEmpty() ){
 SampleResult.setResponseData("OK,"UTF-8");
 prev.setSuccessful(true);
  }
  else{
 SampleResult.setResponseData("ERROR" + errors.toString(),"UTF-8");
 prev.setSuccessful(false);` When the second condition is met the loop ends.